# NumberFormatException while converting binary string to integer

Tags: java, numberformatexception, string-conversion

I am learning bit manipulation in java. So,I am converting binary string to integers bytes and short.
Here is my program :-

```
byte sByte,lByte; // 8 bit
short sShort,lShort; // 16 bit
int sInt,lInt; // 32 bit
sByte= (byte)(int)Integer.valueOf("10000000", 2); //Smallest Byte
lByte= (byte) ~sByte;
sShort= (short)(int)Integer.valueOf("1000000000000000", 2); //Smallest Short
lShort = (short) ~sShort;
sInt = (int) (int)Integer.valueOf("10000000000000000000000000000000", 2); //Smallest Int
lInt= (int)~sInt;
System.out.println("\"10000000\" \"8 bit\" byte=>"+sByte+"\t~byte=>"+lByte);
System.out.println("\"1000000000000000\" \"16 bit\" short=>"+sShort+"\t~short=>"+lShort);
System.out.println("\"10000000000000000000000000000000\" \"32 bit\" int=>"+sInt+"\t~int=>"+lInt);
```

Byte and Short are being converting and giving smallest Byte and smallest Short Value while Integer is not getting converted.

It is throwing NumberFormatException which is as follows :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10000000000000000000000000000000"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:740)
    at com.learnjava.BitsManipulation.start(BitsManipulation.java:14)
    at com.learnjava.learnjava.main(learnjava.java:9)
```

and if i comment those 3 integer converting lines :-

```
//    sInt = (int) (int)Integer.valueOf("10000000000000000000000000000000", 2); //Smallest Int
//    lInt= (int)~sInt;
//    System.out.println("\"10000000000000000000000000000000\" \"32 bit\" int=>"+sInt+"\t~int=>"+lInt);
```

It is giving me output :-

```
"10000000" "8 bit" byte=>-128   ~byte=>127
"1000000000000000" "16 bit" short=>-32768   ~short=>32767
```

which is fine.I have checked length of string twice which is of 32 length and integer is of 32 bit in java in this way it should work while that is not case here.

If i remove one 0 or 1 from 32 length string or replace 1 to 0 then it also works which is as follow :-

```
sInt = (int) (int)Integer.valueOf("00000000000000000000000000000000", 2); //Smallest Int
lInt= (int)~sInt;
System.out.println("\"00000000000000000000000000000000\" \"32 bit\" int=>"+sInt+"\t~int=>"+lInt);


sInt = (int) (int)Integer.valueOf("1000000000000000000000000000000", 2); //Smallest Int
lInt= (int)~sInt;
System.out.println("\"1000000000000000000000000000000\" \"31 bit\" int=>"+sInt+"\t~int=>"+lInt);
```

output is as follows:-

```
"00000000000000000000000000000000" "32 bit" int=>0  ~int=>-1

"1000000000000000000000000000000" "31 bit" int=>1073741824  ~int=>-1073741825
```

i am getting confused on this.
Please tell me reason why it is throwing NumberFormatException and solution for this problem.

Comment: Then what is other way to convert this string into int

Comment: ..use `BigInteger`

Comment: @ErnestKiwele the OP is parsing in radix 2, not in radix 10.

Comment: 2147483647 has 10 digits while short has 16 digits which is getting converted,then   what is reason Short is getting converted. It should also throw an error on short being converted

Answer (score 6):

Short answer:

The Integer.parseInt() method (which is a method called by Integer.valueOf()) requires you to tell it if the number is negative, because it is not designed handle signed numbers. "Fix" your code by adding a minus:

```
Integer sInt = Integer.valueOf("-10000000000000000000000000000000", 2);
System.out.println(sInt); // prints -2147483648
```

---

Long answer:

Your stacktrace tells you where you can find out where things go wrong. Your Integer.valueOf() method calls Integer.parseInt(), which in turn throws a NumberFormatException on line 583. You can find the code for the Integer class in the [openjdk](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/dc4322602480/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l583).

```
public static int parseInt(String s, int radix) throws NumberFormatException {
    int result = 0;
    int i = 0, len = s.length();
    int limit = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int multmin;
    int digit;

    if (len > 0) {
        char firstChar = s.charAt(0);
        if (firstChar < '0') { // Possible leading "+" or "-"
            if (firstChar == '-') {
                negative = true;
                limit = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            } else if (firstChar != '+')
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
        }

        multmin = limit / radix;
        while (i < len) {
            digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i++),radix);
            if (result < multmin) {
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
            }
            result *= radix;
            result -= digit;
        }
    } else {
        throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
    }
    return negative ? result : -result;
}
```

I've removed the parts of the code that our current example does not run through for clarification. Note that limit is -2147483647 (one over the MIN_VALUE)! Likewise, multmin is -1073741823. In the first iteration of the loop, result is 0, so result*radix is 0 and digit is 1 (that's the first number in our String), so result - digit is -1. In the second iteration, digit becomes 0, but now result * radix is -2. In the third iteration, we get -4, then -8, etc... This goes on all the way until result equals -1073741824, which is one fewer than our limit.

Now, we can also see that the method checks if we added a sign (+ or -) to our number. Interestingly, if we do add a minus, we see that limit is set to MIN_VALUE. So, counterintuitively, we can simply "fix" your code by adding a minus:

```
Integer sInt = Integer.valueOf("-10000000000000000000000000000000", 2);
System.out.println(sInt); // prints -2147483648
```

---

On another note, you do some weird casting there. Instead of:

```
sByte= (byte)(int)Integer.valueOf("10000000", 2);
```

You should be able to write:

```
sByte = Byte.valueOf("10000000", 2);
```

I Say "should", because actually you can't. This results in another exception! This is because the Byte.valueOf() method simple calls the Integer.valueOf() method and then casts the answer to a Byte! And because 10000000 for an Integer is 000...00010000000 = 128, it will tell you that that is too large for a Byte.

Whoa! So why does your weird casting trick work? Because of a thing called "silent overflow". Java recognizes you desperately want to fit the number 128 in a Byte, which is not possible, so it puts as many as it can into it (127) and it wraps around to the bottom by adding the remaining 1, leaving you with -128. I suppose this is what silent overflow was designed for, but depending on it is definitely a bad idea. To illustrate what happens in your line:

```
sByte= (byte)(int)Integer.valueOf("10000000", 2);

Integer a = Integer.valueOf("10000000", 2);
System.out.println(a);        // 128
int b = (int)a;
System.out.println(b);        // 128
byte sByte = (byte)b;
System.out.println(sByte);    // -128
```

So, don't use parseInt() or valueOf() on signed numbers.

Answer (score 0):

convert to Long and then long to Int like this in kotlin

```
try {
    val binaryString = "10010100101111111111000010100001"
    if (binaryString.isEmpty()) println("number is empty")
    else {
        val number = binaryString.toLong(2)
        println("number is ${number.toInt()}")
  }

} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.stackTrace.forEach {
        kotlin.io.println("number is ${it.toString()}")
    }
}
```